# Pagination with Swift Php and MySQL

Tags: php, ios, mysql, pagination

I am getting data from my server using this code which fetches 5

```
SELECT Posts.id,
Posts.uuid,
    Posts.caption,
    Posts.path,
    Posts.date,
    USERS.id,
    USERS.username,
    USERS.fullname,
    USERS.email,
    USERS.profileImage
    FROM Blogger.Posts JOIN Blogger.USERS ON
    Posts.id = $id AND USERS.id = $id ORDER by date DESC
    Limit 5
```

Now I am trying to add pagination... So basically I have a loadmore button which when I tap it, I would like to be able to load the next 5.

I haven't been able to find any solution yet, as all the tutorials I have found are for websites and I am trying to do it for a IOS app..?

If anyone can help in anyway or put me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel The answer below.. It seems to work, but if you know a better way I would be happy to consider you Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every request you send to server you should include info about which page you want to load. Your request URL could look like:

```
http://domainname.com/my_api_url.php?page=1
```

For page 1, etc...

Than using PHP you can get page param, like:

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? (int) $_GET["page"] : 1;
```

Based on page you can update your query limit to return different results, like:

```
$sql = '
SELECT Posts.id,
Posts.uuid,
    Posts.caption,
    Posts.path,
    Posts.date,
    USERS.id,
    USERS.username,
    USERS.fullname,
    USERS.email,
    USERS.profileImage
    FROM Blogger.Posts JOIN Blogger.USERS ON
    Posts.id = $id AND USERS.id = $id ORDER by date DESC
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET ' . ($page * 5);
```

Comment: Nice, I have managed to do that... I have added it to a button and it seems to kind of work, but if I press the button mre than 1 time before the request has finished it duplicates the posts...? any idea how to stop that?

Comment: That is client side issue, you should disable button while data is loading. Basically, initially set page in ios app, on button click disable it, send request, when you get data process it, increment page and enable button.

Comment: Yeh I immagined it would be something like that, but what I would like to do is put it call it when I scroll past a certain part of the page... So after scrolling past 3 posts I call this loadmore method, but do you know of any way I can disable the loadmore method untill it has finished? or something?!

Comment: Sorry I am not iOS developer, I don't know how those things work in iOS. Maybe you could open new question here on stackoverflow for that.